How can one dump all static fields of a class that has no instances?
I'm in a static method of a class that has no instances. So jdb doesn't like this, of course:
dump this
No 'this'.  In native or static method

It is actually in the latter: a static method of an object with no instances.)
Trying just dump theClassName does't work (in complains about Name unknown: theClassName) even though it's in a method of theClassName as shown by jdb where.
Thread-0[1] where
  [1] java.lang.Thread.sleep (native method)
  [2] theClassName.someStaticMethod (null)

How can I still dump all the class fields (of theClassName) with jdb? (I can still dump/print them individually as dump theClassName.someStaticField, but there are hundreds of them in my case/application.)
BTW, some Java book says

If you specify the name of a class, dump displays all class (static) methods and variables of the class and also displays the superclass and list of implemented interfaces.

However it doesn't actually seem to work like that. This is on java8's jdb, if it makes any diff.

Have you tried methods theClassName and fields theClassName?

@JakeHolzinger: yes, fields theClassName displays the field names and [their] types properly, but not their values.
